# Remove Python 2.5 on Fedora

Tags: fedora, uninstall, python

I followed this tutorial http://paltman.com/2007/nov/15/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251/ and installed python 2.5. Now when I enter the python terminal it reads python 2.5 and not 2.6.

How do I remove python 2.5? So it reverts back to 2.6?

Python was 2.5 was installed by:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

It was installed on Fedora, I was told changing the Pythonpath would help but I don't know how to do it or what Path to put in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python you installed manually ended up under `/usr/local`, which is the directory for manually installed programs. Since `/usr/local/bin` is usually in the program search path before `/usr/bin` (which is where most distribution-provided executables are), when you run `python`, it runs `/usr/local/bin/python`.

To remove your manually installed python, remove at least `/usr/local/bin/python` (or rename it to `python2.5`, if it's not already a symbolic link to `python2.5`). If you're not using the 2.5 installation at all, remove all of its bits under `/usr/local`: `/usr/local/lib/python2.5`, and probably others such as `/usr/local/man/man1/python*`.